# crumbly plaster

Tags: exterior, plaster

I'm in a new build, timber frame house with the back clad in plaster.
The plaster seems quite "sandy", if that makes sense. If I rub it my hand comes away dusty and gritty.

Around one window I can see the plaster being a little crumbly. Is this an issue I should raise with the management company?

[image]

Comment: That image shows what appears to be an exterior scene.  Where in the world are you?    Typically plaster is not an exterior finish.  You are looking at something I might call "stucco".   Though I'm not experienced with such.

Comment: That surface doesn't look 'finished' to me - as though there's a final step someone forgot. I'd certainly bring it to someone's attention.

Comment: Almost looks like the "brown coat", the 2nd step of stucco application prior to the final, thin "color coat" (although properly mixed stucco is not so crumbly like that). I agree with @brhans, this does not look finished.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, @DaveM is correct: That’s stucco. I live where it’s a “wet climate”, but contractors still try to use stucco from time to time.

Two problems: 1) no metal trim (screed) at the bottom of the stucco, and 2) mixture is improper if it’s deteriorating this quickly.

Here, we don’t use stucco much, so every time someone tries, it’s a disaster because they’re not accustomed to using it. Looks like the same where you live.

Comment: thanks all. Yes, its on the outside of the house. Im based in the UK.

Im meeting the site manager of the development next week. What should i say is missing, i.e. is there a final finish that should have been applied or is it simply mixed wrong and needs replacing?

Im sure he wont replace it as its one house out of about 50 and to replace it on 50 houses would be a massive task, but i can at least flag it and see what he says.

Comment: The problem isn’t that it NOT DONE. The problem is that it’s NOT DONE PROPERLY.  There needs to be ametal screed (metal trim) at the bottom for three reasons: 1) protection of the bottom edge from damage, 2) allow moisture to drain out from behind stucco, and 3) protect the bottom edge from splashing water and deteriorating the stucco. It will continue crumbling until it’s fixed. They may tell you it’s not painted. (The core color is the same as the surface color.) I think that’s true, but putting a coat of paint on it won’t save it from crumbling. (I think a metal edge is required by code. )